# Data load in Websphere commerce

Tags: validation, websphere, websphere-8

We have a requirement to include plus sign in logonId column in out of the box dataloader scripts in Websphere commerce. Below is the error log which is observed while loading the csvs with plus sign in email id. I had tried with -DXmlValidation=false in the data load but did not help. Any pointers on how to load the same?

```
==================================================================================
WebSphere Commerce Data Load
==================================================================================

Dec 3, 2017 12:10:41 AM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.DataLoaderMain logStartDate
INFO: Load started at: Sun Dec 03 00:10:41 GMT 2017
Dec 3, 2017 12:10:56 AM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.DataLoaderMain logInitTime
INFO: Initialization completed in 14.905 seconds.
Dec 3, 2017 12:10:56 AM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.DataLoaderMain execute
INFO:
Processing Person...
Dec 3, 2017 12:10:57 AM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.report.error.LoadItemErrorReport generateErrorLog
FINE:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error report for load item: Person.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Dec 3, 2017 12:10:57 AM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.report.error.LoadItemErrorReport addReportDetails
FINE:

An exception was caught: com.ibm.commerce.member.dataload.exception.MemberDataLoadApplicationException: The value test+123@txtgmail.com of the LOGONID field is invalid.
Application message:
An error occurred while transforming the data object into physical objects.  Data Object: com.ibm.commerce.member.facade.datatypes.impl.PersonTypeImpl@72e972e9 (accountStatus: <unset>, passwordExpired: <unset>, profileType: <unset>, registrationApprovalStatus: null, registrationStatus: RegisteredPerson), Physical objects:
==================================================
Transformed Physical objects:
==================================================
==================================================

Exception message:
The value test+123@txtgmail.com of the LOGONID field is invalid.
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is this should work. You should open a PMR with IBM Support.